# Understanding SQL Server multiple table joins

Tags: sql-server, join

I need some clarification on how multiple joins work in SQL Server.

I have 4 tables, say Table A, Table B, Table C, Table D. All are interrelated (A-B-C-D).

Table A and B form a part of a group (Invoice) and Table B and C another (Order)

Table A has 100 records, B has 90, C has 60 and D has 70.

Relation between A and B is one to many relationship. A-=B, and individually I want to Inner join them (as they are part of Invoice)

D is inner joined with C having one to many relationship. C=-D and individually I want to Inner join them (as they are part of Orders)

Relationship between B and C is one to one and I want to Left Join them. i.e. all the records from B and Null in missing records of C. At the same time, join all the tables. So, I want a total of 90 records (all from table B and Null where they are not present)

```
A-=B--C=-D
```

My understanding was that I could use the following code.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table A AS A
INNER JOIN Table B AS B ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN Table C AS C ON B.Cid = C.Cid AND B.key = C.key
INNER JOIN Table D AS D ON C.Did = D.Did
```

However, this seem to yield incorrect result. I got 70 records. After keeping the join between C and D i.e. the last join in the query a left join I got 100 records.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table A AS A
INNER JOIN Table B AS B ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN Table C AS C ON B.Cid = C.Cid AND B.key = C.key
LEFT JOIN Table D AS D ON C.Did = D.Did
```

Why is this happening and what is the correct way of getting 90 records, i.e. all records from table B and Null where-ever missing.

Comment: i may be wrong, but it seems like you're referring to  B.Cid and  C.Cid as if they're the attributes of the resultant table of your first query, but you did not use a CTE to wrap your first subquery before running the LEFT JOIN on it

Comment: Can you show me in brief how I can achieve this or point me to any documentation or reference which explains CTE very easily.

Comment: If your second query gave you 100 results, that means all 100 rows in table A have a match in Table B.   So why would you expect to see 90 rows?   Which 10 rows should not be returned?

Comment: Specifically, this line of code you wrote:

    `LEFT JOIN Table C AS C ON B.Cid = C.Cid AND B.key = C.key`

Returns NULL values for all fields in the right table if both of the joining conditions (`B.Cid = C.Cid AND B.key = C.key`) do not occur. This may be what is confusing you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make the join between C and D in a subquery, then join it to B. Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table A AS A
INNER JOIN Table B AS B ON A.id = B.id
LEFT JOIN ( 
    SELECT C.Cid, C.key
    FROM Table C AS C
    JOIN Table D AS D ON C.Did = D.Did ) AS CD ON B.Cid = CD.Cid AND B.key = CD.key
```

You can't have equijoin then left join then equijoin across relations without parenthetical (or nested) syntax in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this, It seems like Table B is your base table and not Table A

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table B AS B
INNER JOIN Table A AS A ON B.id = A.id
LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT C.Cid, C.key
FROM Table C AS C
INNER JOIN Table D AS D ON C.Did = D.Did ) AS CD ON B.Cid = CD.Cid AND B.key = CD.key
```

Comment: Switching table B and A like this does not make any difference.

Comment: You are right, It doesn't matter in case of an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table A AS A
 INNER JOIN Table B AS B 
         ON A.id = B.id
 LEFT  JOIN Table C AS C 
       INNER JOIN Table D AS D 
               ON C.Did = D.Did 
         ON B.Cid = C.Cid 
        AND B.key = C.key
```